# How can I get the value of children in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure in Firebase:

[image]

I have the code:

```
DatabaseReference curtidasRef = firebaseRef.child("postagens-curtidas").child(feed.getId()).child("qtdCurtidas");
```

My database structure:

[image]

My question is: How can I get the the value of `qtdCurtidas`?

Comment: is your problem solved @LuisFelipe ?

Comment: not yet, but solution 2 is on the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of your `qtdCurtidas`, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("postagens-curtidas");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            long qtdCurtidas = ds.child("qtdCurtidas").getValue(Long.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "qtdCurtidas: " + qtdCurtidas);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
qtdCurtidas: 1
```

Comment: Your suggestion is correct, but I have more child call 'qtdCurtidas' and I want to get a especific. I want to get 'qtdCurtidas' inside the feed.getId.

Comment: I will add to question a picture of my database

Comment: How can I get this valor inside the feedId? using the same base you spoke in your answer @Alex Mamo

Comment: In the exact way I have showed you in my answer. You can get the values of your qtdCurtidas under each child. Have you tried the code, what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use valueEventListener to get data. First define your variable. As I saw from your screenshot, it is integer variable. Then set valueEventListener  to your DatabaseReference.

```
int myValue;

curtidasRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                             myValue= dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
               //TODO: some codes to handele error
            }
        });
```

Comment: sorry for mistake. I edited code. dataSnapshot should be instead of postSnapshot

Comment: Your answer show a error in myValue "Transform myValue' into final one element array"

Comment: You should define myValue variable as class variable.Such as
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   int myValue;

Comment: You should tell in your code that `myValue` is a global variable, it would otherwise just give the error of making it a final array element.

Comment: The error "Transform myValue' into final one element array", how can I fix? Declaring the variable this way?? "final int[] qtdCurtidas = new int[1];" and " qtdCurtidas[0] = dataSnapshot.child("qtdCurtidas").getValue(Integer.class);" Is this correct?

Comment: why is qtdCurtidas integer array? Do you need to get array from firabase? In that case you should need to use for loop such as below.
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    qtdCurtidas[i] =postSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
}